# Is this impossible get name of class and set for variable inside class?

Tags: java

When I create:

```
player huhu = new player();
```

I want to get "huhu" to String name inside player;

```
public class player{
    String name = ??? How to get "huhu" here?
    ....
}
```

Sorry for my poor english!

Comment: I can't imagine that's possible.  You can, however, do this: `Player huhu = new Player("huhu");` Then you could set the value of _name_ to the argument passed in the constructor.

Comment: Variable names and the values of string variables have nothing to do with each other.  The best you could do is `Player huhu = new Player("huhu");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Player {
    private String name;

    public Player(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
}

Player huhu = new Player("huhu");
```

Notice that I'm capitalizing the name of the class.

You should *always* capitalize your class names.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access the local variables' names using standard Java.

If you really need access to the name, you'll have to pass it as a constructor parameter, as specified in some of the comments. That would require you, however, to change your code to support this for each and every variable you declare.

I'm seriously scared to ask why you need this functionality.

Comment: Agreed... This question begs the question: "_what are you trying to accomplish_?"!

Comment: Yes. Quite frankly, I can't see an answer to this question that won't result in a royal facepalm.

Comment: Thanks you so... But I think this is my answer "Player huhu = new Player("huhu"); I do my exercises. I has just study java.